# NullPointerException while Looping through Edges and Vertices of Graph

Tags: java, loops, graph, nullpointerexception, iteration

I am trying to loop through the vertices I have in a graph and list their edges as I go. So far I have been able to come up with the following code:

```
public String displayRecords()
{
    String printOut = null;
    for (ListIterator<Vert> iter = graph.listIterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) 
    {
        Vert displayVert = iter.next();
        boolean cont = true;
        int floop = 0;
        Edge tempEdge = null;
        //extra vars
        String pname = null;
        String sname = null;
        int dist = 0;
        do
        {
            if(floop == 0)
            {
                tempEdge = displayVert.firstEdge;
                pname = displayVert.name;
                sname = tempEdge.parentNode.name;
                dist = tempEdge.edgeLen;
                floop++;
            }else{
                tempEdge = tempEdge.nextEdge; 
            }

            printOut = printOut + pname + sname + dist + "Plane";

        }while(tempEdge.nextEdge.parentNode != null);
    }
    return printOut;
}
```

However, I keep getting a `NullPointerException` at this line:

```
}while(tempEdge.nextEdge.parentNode != null);
```

Here is my code for the `Vert` and `Edge` classes:

```
class Vert {
   public Edge firstEdge;
    public String name; 
   // other node info here

   public Vert() {
      firstEdge = null;

   }

    public Vert(String n)
    {
        firstEdge = null;
        name = n;   
    }
}

class Edge {
   public Vert parentNode = null; 
   public Edge nextEdge = null; // next in adj list
   // other edge info here
   public int edgeLen; // edge length

   public Edge(Vert num, Edge e, int len) {
      parentNode = num;
      nextEdge = e;
      // initialize other edge info here
      edgeLen = len;
   }

}
```

What am I doing wrong and is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Either tempEdge or nextEdge isn't properly initialized.

Comment: how so? they have elements, by default `parentNode` is set to `null` but why is it giving me a nullpointerexception when I am checking to see if its null?

Comment: You should also post the code for the `Edge` class and perhaps a minimal set of test data that leads to the NPE. However, it is already clear that either `tempEdge` or `tempEdge.nextEdge` is `null` when you get the NPE.

Comment: @Axel but I get the NPE when the program gets to `}while(tempEdge.nextEdge.parentNode != null);`, I am trying to check for the end of the `edge` and stop looping. What other way is there to determine the end of an adjacency list? should I use a flag?

Comment: Just put if (tempEdge == null) System.out.print("I am a null"); and if (tempEdge.nextEdge == null) System.out.print("No! I am a null"); statements before the while and check who is causing problems.

Comment: @Axel I have also included class `vert` and `edge`. @filip the compiler is telling me its `}while(tempEdge.nextEdge.parentNode != null);`

Comment: In your Vert class firstEdge is always null. Why is that?

Comment: @filip because I initiate it in another class since its a public variable, `ref.get(val1).firstEdge = _edge;` so the class that initiates this takes in commands from the user and stores them and on their request the info should be printed

Comment: Never do that, the whole point of the constructor is to initialize variables properly. You are just asking for null pointer exceptions. Please rewrite your Vert class so that the constructors do the initialization.

Comment: but how can I fix this right now? I dont think the fact that I didnt initialize the variables is causing NPE since the program fills in firstEdge 2 lines after `vert` is initiated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58886/discussion-between-filip-and-ahoura-ghotbi).

Answer (score 0):

You set `tempEdge` to null and `floop` to `0`, which means the `else` statement will run. I feel that is the point where the `NullPointerException` occurs. Otherwise, if you do not set the `nextEdge` field to anything, it will be `null`, it which you will get a `NullPointerException` when you try to access the field `parentNode` through this `null` item.

Either initialize your `tempEdge` to be something other than `null`, or change the while loop to be:

```
while(tempEdge.nextEdge != null && tempEdge.nextEdge.parentNode != null);
```

which will break if the `nextEdge` field is `null`. If it is not, you can safely proceed to the next condition, which is what you really want to test.

Comment: I tried your `while` and it didnt work, I have pasted class `edge` and `vert` in the original post, that should give you a better understanding of what I am doing I guess

Comment: @AhouraGhotbi If you still get a `NullPointerException` with that while loop, it means that `tempEdge` is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your problem:

```
tempEdge = tempEdge.nextEdge;
```

If you let your loop run for long enough, eventually you'll set `tempEdge` to `null`, and then your condition here:

```
}while(tempEdge.nextEdge.parentNode != null);
```

will throw a `NullPointerException`. You might instead want to revise it to

```
}while(tempEdge != null && tempEdge.parentNode != null);
```

This way the do while loop will break when `tempEdge` is `null`, i.e. when you have run off the edge of the list, or when it's `parentNode` is `null`.

The cool thing is that if `tempEdge` is in fact `null`, the condition will evaluate to false before checking `tempEdge.parentNode`, so the condition should never throw a `NullPointerException`.

Now if after this you're still getting a `NullPointerException`, the only answer is that it's broken the first time you go through it. A do while loop always runs once, even if the condition isn't met. If this is happening, it means that your first `tempEdge` has a `null` `parentNode`, which is probably a design issue more than anything else.

Comment: just tried your solution and it didnt work! I am now getting NPE on `tempEdge.parentNode.name;` !!!

Comment: @AhouraGhotbi Understood. I have revised my answer appropriately.

Comment: unfortunately it still didnt help, I am still getting NPE on `tempEdge.parentNode.name`!

Comment: @AhouraGhotbi In that case make it a while loop instead of a do while. Looks like it's the first case that's causing the issue.

Comment: @AhouraGhotbi Also, it seems like there's a design issue at play here. If the first case is breaking, you're probably not setting `parentNode` appropriately in the first place.